# using Directory class, check directories for certain filetypes

Tags: c#, directory

I have been using the following lines to search a folder structure for specific filetypes and just copy those filetypes and maintain their original folder structure. It works very well.
Is there any modification I can make to my method to only copy the directories that contain the filtered filetype?

*edit: I can let the user select a only certain set of files, (example *.dwg or *.pdf), using text box named txtFilter.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourceFolder = txtSource.Text;
    string destinationFolder = txtDestination.Text;
    CopyFolderContents(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
}

// Copies the contents of a folder, including subfolders to an other folder, overwriting existing files
public void CopyFolderContents(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder)
        {
            string filter = txtFilter.Text;

            if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
            {
                // Copy folder structure
                foreach (string sourceSubFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceSubFolder.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder));
                }

                // Copy files
                foreach (string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
                    File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your main loop?

```
if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceSubFolder, "*.pdf").Any())
       Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceSubFolder.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder));
```

or for multiple file types:

```
if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceSubFolder).Where(x => x.ToLower.EndsWith(".pdf") || x.ToLower.EndsWith(".dwg")).Any())
       Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceSubFolder.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder));
```

Comment: Actually, .Any() would be a better choice than Count.  You don't care how many there are, just that there are some.

Comment: if(.Count) would be the same as .Count > 0  Try it out. Assuming .Count can't return a negative number I think. But I take your point on the .Any() regardless.

Comment: Any would be faster. Once it found a single file it will return, while Count would continue until the last file

Comment: This worked on the first try. Thank you. Where do I check off that this is the solution?

Comment: 1. .Net 4+ already has the `searchPattern` overload. 2. Note to all answers: Using `Replace` is highly unsafe in this context, should strip and `Path.Combine` instead, to avoid annoying `/` problems.

Comment: ... Also use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToLower()`. Altogether the performance of this snip will be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate both operations into one loop and complete the algorithm in O(n).

```
foreach(string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFile.Replace(sourceFolder,destinationFolder)));
    File.Copy(sourceFile,sourceFile.Replace(sourceFolder,destinationFolder),true);
}
```

Comment: That is just an algorithm for the core problem. It assumes exceptions would be taken care.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distinct directories from the files you find, then iterate through them and create the directories before copying the files.

```
        if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach(string directory in files.Select(f => Path.GetDirectoryName(f)).Distinct())
            {
                string destinationDirectory = directory.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);

                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);                        
                }
            }

            foreach (string sourceFile in files)
            {
                string destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
            }
        }
```